# javascript: форматирование строк (дополнение чисел нулями слева)

Tags: javascript, строки, format

подскажите на 2021 год в javascript появилось какое-нибудь встроенное средство для форматирования строк, чтобы к примеру можно было бы вывести список целых чисел дополненных слева нулями, типа `%02d`?

что-нибудь типа

```
const value = 7;
const text = `{value}.02d`
```

или придется использовать сторонние библиотеки/писать свой код?

Comment: Возможно, `7..toFixed(2)`?

Comment: Есть ещё [`String.prototype.padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) и [`String.prototype.padEnd()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)

Comment: я имел в виду, чтобы '7' превратилось в `07`

Comment: `'7'.padStart(2, '0')`?